# MediaWiki: How to put $wgSitename in the sidebar?

Tags: mediawiki

I'm working on a group of related wikis. I want `$wgSitename` to show up prominently in the left sidebar. What's a good way to do this?

I could hack the skin but this is not a good way.
I looked into [MediaWiki:Sidebar](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Interface/Sidebar) but there's no obvious way to get the site name in there.

There will be more than 10 wikis and I don't want to create a different logo for each wiki.

Comment: use the logoimage instead?

Comment: Don't really want to do that with 10 different wikis. I want to keep it as simple as possible. I'm currently thinking pywikibot may be the best way to do that since I'll be using pwb anyway and I could just write a couple of lines in Python that update MediaWiki:Sidebar based on $wgSitename but I'm still hoping for a simpler solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `* {{SITENAME}}` to `MediaWiki:Sidebar` and use some script to replicate that, or use the [AddMessages](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:AddMessages) extension or the [MessagesPreLoad](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/MessagesPreLoad) hook to set the text from code.

Comment: Thanks. I think I tried something like this but didn't get it to work before.    In fact `* {{SITENAME}}` and `** {{SITENAME}}` don't work, but  `** mainpage|{{SITENAME}}` works well for me.

Comment: Yeah, looks like headings cannot fall back to be plain strings, they must be messages. So you must put `{{SITENAME}}` into MediaWiki:Something (or dynamically via the hook) and refer to that.

Comment: If you don't care about the sitename being in the heading, you can also use the [SkinBuildSidebar](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/SkinBuildSidebar) hook, that gives you more control.